# Scrape Broken Up Images and Join them to make Complete images for Ebook creation

Tags: php, html, image, pdf, web-scraping

I need to scrape images from a novel website in order to create ebooks (PDFs) from the images for offline reading. This website has each single page of a novel and a Next and a Previous button to go through the pages.

The problem is that the image shown on this site is actually broken up into smaller images.

As an example, you can see this novel here: http://kitaabghar.org/bookshelf01/AhmedShaheer/RedEyeImranSeriesNovel.php

OR

http://kitaabghar.org/bookshelf01/AhmedShaheer/RedEyeImranSeriesNovel.php?page=1

The image that is shown on the site is made up of three images which are as follows,

1. http://urdunovels.kitaabghar.org/A-Shelf/AhmedShaheer/RedEyeImranSeriesNovel/us1a6s0i3st1nr2e0d1e6ye-1.gif
2. http://urdunovels.kitaabghar.org/A-Shelf/AhmedShaheer/RedEyeImranSeriesNovel/ls1a6s0i3st1nr2e0d1e6ye-1.gif
3. http://urdunovels.kitaabghar.org/A-Shelf/AhmedShaheer/RedEyeImranSeriesNovel/rs1a6s0i3st1nr2e0d1e6ye-1.gif

Each next page increments a number in the URL like so,
http://kitaabghar.org/bookshelf01/AhmedShaheer/RedEyeImranSeriesNovel.php?page=2
http://kitaabghar.org/bookshelf01/AhmedShaheer/RedEyeImranSeriesNovel.php?page=3

I have found a way with curl but that works with full images, not the broken up ones like these.

> So, I only needed to go to each magazine, check the url and then curl all the jpeg's:
>
> ```
> curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0' -v -o ./#1.jpg http://website.com/random/generated/links/[x-xx]/more/random/goodness
> ```
>
> Where x-xx specifies the number range of the jpegs, indicating the page number. -o specifies that the files are named in the current directory the shell is in, and the # specifies that the filename used is the same number the variable in the link is, because all the jpegs on the site are named as 0.jpeg. Don't know why, but number 1 had to be after the # for it to work. the -A specifies a user agent, which in this situation is the newest Firefox running in Linux, since apparently some servers can notice the use of wget and curl and even block those connections. This makes them think that you are just a user coming to the site with a Firefox on Linux.
>
> Now I just need to convert them to pdf with imagemagick (which is very, very handy tool for everything). I just entered:
>
> ```
> convert `ls -1v` file.pdf
> ```
>
> And I get a pdf file with all the jpgs in it in a numerical order. Now just chuck that into any device and happy offline reading.

**NOTE:** This is not my own method but someone else's. Nonetheless, it works on a number of sites that contain unbroken images. But not on this site.

Any help would be appreciated.

REGARDS

Comment: Does the site allow you to copy their content?  Could you ask them to let you have access to the full pages?

Comment: As far as I know, they don't.

Some novels have download links, like this one: http://kitaabghar.com/bookbase/mazhar/Cyrus-Imran-Series-Urdu-Novel.html

Others don't, like the one mentioned in the question, i.e. http://kitaabghar.com/bookbase/mazhar/HawkEyeImranSeriesNovel.html

Comment: Well, if the site does not allow to copy content, then what you are trying to do is illegal - and you are asking for help doing something illegal.  I wouldn't count on getting much help...

Comment: If it were illegal then why would they allow downloading of newer novels and not the older ones? If I understand correctly, they don't allow older downloads simply because they haven't updated their site for quite some time and haven't gotten around uploading and putting up links to the older files. Then how is this illegal?

Comment: I shouldn't say this but this is the trend in our country. People mainly focus on newer things and leave the old ones be. :(

Comment: I found a way on my own. Please mark this as finished.